# How to plot the output of a command

Tags: shell, utilities, plotting

How can I plot the output of this command line with GNUPlot? What should the diagram script look like?

I want a histogram.

```
wget -O - -o /dev/null http://www.stackoverflow.com/ |
cat | cat | sed "s/</\n</g" |
grep '<\/\{0,1\}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\:\._\-]\{0,\}' |
cut -f 2 -d"<" | cut -f 1 -d">" | cut -f 1 -d" " |
sed "s/\//\\n/g" |
sort | uniq -c |
tail -n +2 |
cut -c5-
```

Comment: Since the first invocation of sed(1) seems wrong, and you didn't mention what kind of data you want to plot, it is difficult to answer your question. :)

Comment: @cinsk how is that `sed` wrong?  It inserts a newline before each `<`.  Correctly.

Comment: I don't remember how to work gnuplot, I just use the help facility every time I want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you out. Write data to file (changed `cut -c5-` to `cut -c4-` because it was deleting the first digit):

```
wget -O - -o /dev/null http://www.stackoverflow.com/ | cat | sed "s/</\n</g" | grep '<\/\{0,1\}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\:\._\-]\{0,\}' | cut -f 2 -d"<" | cut -f 1 -d">" | cut -f 1 -d" " | sed "s/\//\\n/g" | sort | uniq -c | tail -n +2 | cut -c4- > mydata.txt
```

Create `myplot.dem` (some custom initialization added here, change it as you like it):

```
set style data histogram
set style fill solid border -1
set log y
set boxwidth 0.9
set term png
set tics out nomirror
set xtics rotate by -45
set output "histogram.png"
plot "mydata.txt" using 1:xticlabels(2)
```

and finally:

```
gnuplot myplot.dem
```

creates your plot "histogram.png" in current directory.